# Detect deadloop in PinTool

Tags: intel-pin

I am writing a PinTool, which can manipulate certain register/memory value. However, after manipulation, one challenge I am facing now, is the `deadloop`.

In particular, due to the frequent manipulation of certain register value, it is indeed common to create `deadloop` in the execution trace. I am thinking to detect such case, and terminate the execution.

**So here is my question, what is a good practice to detect a `deadloop` in a PinTool?** I can come up with some naive solutions, say, record the executed instructions, and if certain instruction has been executed for a large amount of times, just terminate the execution.

Could anyone help me on this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting whether a program will terminate isn't a computable problem in general, so no, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: I mean, as I am doing dynamic analysis, I can cut the execution when the processing time exceeds a pre-defined threshold.. Do you think it is a good idea?

Comment: How do you know that the predefined limit is due to an issue with the loop variable as opposed to a very long loop?